# Socket not created by this factory with spark streaming and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, httpclient

I am hitting this exception with spark streaming S3 access.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Socket not created by this factory
at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.isSecure(SSLSocketFactory.java:435)...
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)...

at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists ...
```

I have tried these steps [from other threads like [AWS Socket Not created by this factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908610/aws-socket-not-created-by-this-factory) or [Cannot use AWS SDK in Spring Boot Application (Socket not created by this factory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061279/cannot-use-aws-sdk-in-spring-boot-application-socket-not-created-by-this-factor) ] and didn't work.

- Shading the all amazonaws and apache http jars.
- Upgrade httpclient and httpcore explicitly to 4.5.x.
- Upgrade amazon sdk to 1.11.x.
- Upgrade hadoop to 3.1.x.

None of this worked and I am stuck for 2 days now which means I have tried most of the solutions in stackoverflow and internet already. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is "new", but spark has upgraded to a version of httpclient which breaks s3a in hadoop 2.8 in some cases. this sounds like one of the symptoms

I would recommend grabbing the ASF hadoop download consistent with those in the spark release you are using and then dropping in the (hadoop-aws, aws-*, http*) JARs from that release. Or build spark yourself with the -Phadoop-cloud profile and let maven do the work.